# XGB Preformance better than Neural Net

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I am working on an ETA prediction problem. The thing is while my xgb model is by far best with mae of 1.12 and for the same dataset I've also applied a simple 3 layered network with relu activation in hidden and a linear activation at dense with adam with default values of beta1 and beta2 but with lr=0.00001 (as this is slightly working better). The Problem is xgb is performing much better than nn with 3,4,5 layers upto 9 although after 5 the performance saturates combinations with dropouts and batch normalization have also been tested. Below are plots

xgb modeling....

[image: Actual ETA(Black) for all orders on that date vs Predicted ETA(red) and below is RMSE Plot Date wise]

NN Modeling...
[image: Actual ETA(Black) for all orders on that date vs Predicted ETA(red) and below is RMSE Plot Date wise]

As you can see the xgb is modeling actual quite accurately. The issue is this performance is not acceptable by management so I need to increase the performance, I haven't tried LSTM or any rnn, as I thought that will be over-kill. Any suggestion will help...

Thanks

Comment: You could at first chage de activation with selu instead of relu. The fact that your nn is not performing further better even though tou add layers, makes me think that you have a vanishing gradient problem. The SELU activation avoids it. Remember to nitialize your weight with lecun_norm

Comment: Do you mean that the score for xgb model is too low according to the management? What makes you think that NN should perform better? NN are not inherently better for most of applications and are known to have problems with generalisation.

Comment: What *exactly* is your *question*?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski The MAE with xgboost is around 1.074 (Days) Which is high as we would be happy with MAE close to 0.7 -0.8 (Days). Yes Even I didn't expect to NN outperform xgb as tree based structure are quite good for these problems  but at the same time I don't know if this is best nn in terms of performance.

Comment: @3nomis Yes will test this config out and let you know.

Comment: @desertnaut My question is do you have any suggestions on how to improve performance algorithmically not just using more data or features and We can have very limited features in live prediction and almost all are currently being used.

Comment: Please edit your post to explicitly include this; but in any case, sounds like too broad a question for SO

Comment: @desertnaut sure will include that